# WSO2 Switch Mediator regex not working properly

Tags: regex, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use regex to match values in a switch statement, so I don't have to create a separate case for similar values.

```
   <switch xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="$ctx:val">
      <case regex="5 | 2">
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="log1" value="hit"/>
         </log>
      </case>
   </switch>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.  It works if I create two separate cases for "5" and "2".  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the spaces from your regex like this: `regex="5|2"`

Comment: I tried that as well, still no luck

Comment: Oops.  That did seem to work when I tried it again.  Thanks bud!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces will be treated as literal characters in regex that are required for the match. Simply remove them:

```
<case regex="5|2">
```